# Delete multiline pattern containing another pattern

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I would to like to delete all instances of a pattern which contain another specified pattern (conveniently on a new line):

```
MID:
```

Sample Input:

```
header
BEGIN:
1abc
7wurw
END:
BEGIN:
22xyz
MID:
34utov
END:
```

Desired Output:

```
header
BEGIN:
1abc
7wurw
END:
```

I'm looking for possible one liners. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -e :a -e '/^BEGIN:/,/^END:/ { /END:/!{$!{N;ba};};/MID:/d;}' inputfile
```

For your input, it'd return:

```
header
BEGIN:
1abc
7wurw
END:
```

Comment: brilliant! thank you <3 I got an error with my out-of-the-box BSD sed on my machine, but with GNU sed it's working as intended

Comment: @okapiho Sorry, I should have added using GNU sed.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `RS, ORS` variable. here is one-liner:

```
awk -v RS="BEGIN:\n" -v ORS="" '/MID/{next}NR>1{printf RS}7' file
```

test with your file:

```
kent$  cat f
header
BEGIN:
1abc
7wurw
END:
BEGIN:
22xyz
MID:
34utov
END:

kent$  awk -v RS="BEGIN:\n" -v ORS="" '/MID/{next}NR>1{printf RS}7' f
header
BEGIN:
1abc
7wurw
END:
```

note, `printf RS` is not very nice, I used it because I know it is `BEGIN:` good practice would be `printf "%s", RS`

Comment: nice :-) but what's the meaning of the "7" at the end?

Comment: @Ronald the 7 is equal to 42 here ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl so I found out, but I didn't know this syntactical construct. As I discovered anything but zero prints the entire "line". So I guess it's something like: An expression evaluating to true (nonzero if numerical) and a default action (print). Correct?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on sample:

```
sed '/BEGIN:/,/END:/{/BEGIN/{h;d};H;/END:/!d;x;/MID:/d}' input.txt
```

I am pretty sure it can be simplified a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN { in_block = 0; }
/BEGIN:/ { in_block = 1; lineno = 0; arr[lineno] = $0; must_write = 1; next; }
/END:/ { in_block = 0; 
         if (must_write == 1) {
              for (i = 0; i <= lineno; ++i) print arr[i]; print; 
         }
         next;
}
/MID:/ { must_write = 0; next; }
in_block == 1 && must_write == 1 { lineno++; arr[lineno] = $0; next; }
in_block == 0 { print }
```

This should work (worked with the supplied test case). Some awk-wizards will find a denser solution, probably. But you can use this kind of processing also for other tasks.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^BEGIN:/{:a;$!{N;/END:/!ba};/MID:/d}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This `gnu awk` divides section by the `END:` so its not true to `BEGIN:`-`END:`, but works:

```
awk '!/MID:/{printf "%s%s\n",$0,RT}' RS="END:" t
header
BEGIN:
1abc
7wurw
END:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/BEGIN:/,/END:/ {
   H
   /END:/ {
      s/.*//
      x
      /\nMID:/ !p
      }
   }' YourFile
```

For OneLiner

```
sed -n '/BEGIN:/,/END:/{H;/END/{s/.*//;x;/\nMID:/ !p;};}' YourFile
```

would not work with the last ; (i have to keep a "\n" on my AIX) (should work on GNU sed)

```
#for AIX
sed -n '/BEGIN:/,/END:/{H;/END/{s/.*//;x;/\nMID:/ !p;}
}' YourFile
```